# How to get the number of bytes read from a pending or aborted overlapped ReadFile operation

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn, readfile, overlapped-io

One can use the `GetOverlappedResult()` function to get the number of read bytes from a successfull overlapped (asynchronous) `ReadFile()` operation.

I can't find a way to get the number of read bytes while the operation is still pending or after it has been aborted. The `GetOverlappedResult()` function seems to set the number of read bytes to 0 in both case.
Any idea how to do that?

Edit: This asynchronous I/O operation is performed to retrieve data coming from an embedded device through a COM port. The operation is aborted after a timeout. I need the number of received bytes before operation was aborted only for debugging purpose.

Comment: You are asking for a time machine.  This just isn't possible, you have to wait until the overlapped I/O request is complete.  If you aborted it then of course you should not care.

Comment: It would probably help if you described *why* you want to do this (i.e. what are you trying to solve that, knowing how much data is present-but-not-retrieved in an async-io request will solve for you). Chances are if it is for data stream integrity to restart the operation after "rewinding" to a prior state your model of async-transfer is probably broken from the get-go.

Comment: @WhozCraig I edited my question to give more details on the context. So yes there are issues in the data stream integrity and I just want some information about what exactly was received. But maybe I should use the ClearComError function, which can fill a structure giving the number of bytes received and not yet read with a ReadFile. Is overlapped ReadFile leave data in this queue until there is enough data to complete the operation succesfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ClearComError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363180%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function can fill a structure giving the number of bytes received and not yet consumed by a `ReadFile` operation.